# ¿Como puedo solucionar este problema de xampp?

Tags: apache, xampp

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

E intentado buscar en la ruta C:\Apache24\bin\httpd.exe" -k runservice
pero yo no tengo esa carpeta en esa ruta

Answer (score 0):

La solucion es sencilla simplemente siga los siguientes pasos:

1. Win + R y escriba regedit luego ingrese
2. Abra este directorio HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE \ SYSTEM \ CurrentControlSet \ Services \ Apache2.4
3. Haz clic derecho en "ImagePath" y elige "Modificar"
4. Cambie el campo Información del valor con su ruta instalada actual de apache en XAMPP
   En mi caso, el valor es "c:\xampp\apache\bin\httpd.exe" -k runservice